# Куча была повреждена 0x00007FFFEC3027F0

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память, visual-studio-2019

Я ослеп что-ли? Где тут ошибка? (n <= 250).

```
u16** d = new u16*[n];
i8** pl = new i8*[n];
for (i8 i(0); i < n; ++i) {
    pl[i] = new i8[i];
    d[i] = new u16[i];
    for (i8 j(0); j < n; ++j) {
        d[i][j] = -1;
        cin >> pl[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем Вы кучу повредили. Верните все как было. ))

Comment: Сама виновата. Ей за вредность. xd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вас не смущает, что в строках

```
for (i8 i(0); i < n; ++i) {
    pl[i] = new i8[i];
    d[i] = new u16[i];
```

Вы выделяете массивы размером 0 (уже проблема!), потом 1, потом... элементов, а потом загоняете в них

```
    for (i8 j(0); j < n; ++j) {
        d[i][j] = -1;
```

`n` элементов в каждый? Выходя за границы выделенной памяти?

Comment: Да, я слепой. Спасибо большое! Я хотел n там написать, а не i.

Comment: А разве массив из 0 элементов выделять нельзя?

Comment: @Qwertiy Насколько я помню (возможно, ошибаюсь), там UB в том плане, что это может быть и нормальный адрес, и нулевой. Словом, тут слово гуру в стандартах. Нашел пока, что "в С++ отсутствуют массивы нулевой длины", но тут надо копаться серьезно...